# Will a shared apk appear on app statistics?

Tags: android, google-play

Suppose my users, download the app from playstore and then
share the apk using file sharing apps (xender,shareit) will it appear on **"Current installs by user"** chart?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Absolutely not. For this you can use google analytic in firebase console to analyse your app installation and users.